# Not able to copy data from one table to another

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: **trade** and **user_pokemon_db**

I want to copy a specific rows from user_pokemon_db, when an event occurs.

Html code:

```
echo "<a href='tradecenter.php' onClick='document.write(".trade($db_id).")' >Put in Trade</a>";
```

When the user clicks on the link, the php function is called which consists on sql query to copy the row.

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO trade (trade_id, user_id, pkmn_id, level, exp, health, attack1, attack2, attack3) 
SELECT (id, user_id, pkmn_id, level, exp, health, attack1, attack2, attack3) 
FROM user_pokemon_db WHERE user_id = '".$id."' AND id = '".$db_id."' ";
```

Problem maybe due to improper writting of the query.. or maybe due to improper formatting of the href!??

What should I do?

Comment: Use select * into newTableName from oldTablename...

Comment: Both your query & HTML code seems to be wrong.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I have the feeling that you are mixing Javascript and PHP.
Clicking on a HTML Link can not call directly a PHP function !
Check your HTML source in your browser to understand what happens

Comment: @steven well, when i run it..! it worked! but problem was function run directly..without clicking on it!

Comment: @Steven can you suggest a better idea to run sql query when user clicks on href? I think that would solve problem.

Comment: @Jens there aren't any errors...

Comment: @user3672971 yes because when you write : 
echo "<a href='tradecenter.php' onClick='document.write(".trade($db_id).")' >Put in Trade</a>";

You are calling the PHP function trade($db_id). 
onclick="" calls javascript (client side) code and not PHP (server side)

Comment: Use Ajax to call a page which will run your php function without refreshing the current page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the content of your php function trade() but it seems that you are confusing javascript and PHP.

Keep in mind that in most of case, once the web page is sent to the user browser, the PHP execution is finished. If you want to do a SQL request after a link click, you need to load a new page or to use something like Ajax to run some PHP code again.

The simplest way to do what you want is to pass the pokemon id as a GET variable (= in the URL) 
and check this variable on another page and generate the good SQL query :

```
echo '<a href="trade.php?pokemon_id='.$id.'" >Trade </a>' ;
```

And the trade.php would do something like that :

```
$id = $_GET['pokemon_id'] ; // Be Aware of SQL Injections !!
trade($id);
```

Have a look at this page for more information about forms  : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

( And if you are using GET or POST variables in your SQL query, be aware of  [SQL Injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) )

If you want to run your PHP function without reloading the page, you should use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP). Check this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP) to understand how it works. A very easy way to use it is to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: is there any way to hide it from the user?? like can i use POST instead of get!?? for safety?

Comment: Yes, with a form using the POST method. 

But I think you don't need to hide that to the user (depending if the pokemon id has to stay secret or not, I don't know your code). 

Just make sure that the content of the $_GET['id'] is numeric with for example is_numeric() before doing any sql query using this variable.

Comment: ohkk thnks! helped alot!